# Deploying Django Project

Tags: python, apache2, web-deployment

I have a django project which I want to deploy on apache2 Http Server.

However, I want to automatically copy all the python files from some directory to apache srv directory which is /srv/www/myproject. Is there any automatic python tool which could solve the purpose.

I have looked into DistUtils and setup.py but I am unsure about how I would copy all .py files (along with directory structure) to the apache directory.

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: With DistUtils you can create an installer. But you'll have to distribute the package somehow. If using a RPM-base Linux, you can create a .rpm package  using `rpmbuild -ba build.spec`, but this requires some more knowledge on the RPM system. A much easier way to do is using `fabric` as already answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org), it is a great tool to do automatic deployments

Answer (score 0):

From the django tutorial:

> If your background is in PHP, you're probably used to putting code
>   under the Web server's document root (in a place such as /var/www).
>   With Django, you don't do that. It's not a good idea to put any of
>   this Python code within your Web server's document root, because it
>   risks the possibility that people may be able to view your code over
>   the Web. That's not good for security.
>
> Put your code in some directory outside of the document root, such as
>   /home/mycode.

For copying files, you can use something as simple as FTP/SCP which you can automate; or you can use more full blown deployment options like fabric (see [this blog entry](http://www.morethanseven.net/2009/07/27/fabric-django-git-apache-mod_wsgi-virtualenv-and-p.html) for a step-by-step guide on fabric + virtualenv + apache mod_wsgi).

You can use any tool to automate the task; but please put the code in the appropriate non-web browsable directory.